# Non uniquely ergodic interval exchange transformations

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Consider an interval exchange transformation that is, a bijective piecewise continuous map $[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1] $ whose restriction to its continuity intervals are translations. Assume that it is minimal and non uniquely ergodic.

Do the ergodic probability measures necessarily give the same weight to each of its continuity intervals?

I would naively expect the answer to this question to be negative, but since I have no example to test it

Thank you all!

Selim

**Edit** As Uri Bader pointed out in the comments, conjugating by a well chosen IET, any minimal non-uniquely ergodic IET provides a negative answer to the question, but the price to pay is to increase the number of continuity intervals involved. The 'good' question concerns then the IETs whose number of interval is minimal in its conjugacy class.

Comment: When you say "do the measures give the same weight to each of its intervals", do you mean continuity intervals? (If not, any two distinct measures give different measure to some interval).

Comment: Yes of course that's what I meant :)

Comment: Maybe you could edit the question to make this clear?

Comment: It seems to me that by conjugating with an iet which has one break point I can always break a continuity interval into two in an arbitrary inner point (which I will move to 0), so the answer is negative, but this feels like cheatting...

Comment: Selim, this is just to check: consider the interval exchange that breaks $[0,1]$ into two halves and interchanges them. You may say that it has two continuity intervals $[0,1/2]$ and $[1/2,1]$. But you may also view this as a continuous half rotation of the circle. What is it to you? In the former case my remark above applies, and the answer to your question is clearly negative.

Comment: You are perfectly right, once again my question is not precise enough; I must ask that the transformation I am considering is in 'reduced form' that is with as little continuity intervals as possible up to conjugating by a rotation.

Comment: Selim: you mean, up to conjugating by an arbitrary interval exchange transformation.

Comment: Oh yes, indeed.

Comment: Then you should edit.

Comment: I would expect a negative answer anyway. You should look at the example in section 4 here http://iml.univ-mrs.fr/~ferenczi/coursfoues.pdf

Comment: The "translation" tag is normally used to refer to translation of mathematics between different languages, so I've removed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The space of invariant probability measures of a minimal interval exchange transformation $T$ on $d$ intervals $I_1, \dots, I_d$ is parametrized by a subsimplex $\mathcal{M}$ of the standard simplex $\Delta=\{(x_1,\dots,x_d)\in\mathbb{R}^d_+: \sum x_i=1\}$ in the sense that:

1) a point $(x_1,\dots, x_d)\in\mathcal{M}$ has the form $(x_1,\dots, x_d) = (\mu(I_1),\dots,\mu(I_d))$ for a $T$-invariant probability measure $\mu$.

2) the ergodic $T$-invariant probability measures correspond to the extremal points of $\mathcal{M}$.

This fact is explained in Section 4 of Ferenczi's notes (as pointed out by Uri Bader in the comments) and also Yoccoz's 'Pisa lecture notes' (https://www.college-de-france.fr/media/jean-christophe-yoccoz/UPL15305_PisaLecturesJCY2007.pdf). Very roughly speaking, $\mathcal{M}$ is obtained as a decreasing intersection of the successive images of the standard simplex $\Delta$ under the projective actions of the matrices prescribed by repeated iteration of the Rauzy-Veech algorithm starting with $T$.

In the case of a minimal non-uniquely ergodic interval exchange transformation $T$, the distinct ergodic invariant probability measures correspond to distinct points in $\Delta$ and, hence, it is always the case that some (actually, all but possibly one) ergodic probability measure does not give the same weight to all (continuity) intervals.

Comment: Thank you very much Matheus for taking the time to give this detailed answer!

Comment: You're welcome!